# Proportion expected in a simulation

Tags: probability-theory, simulation

X and Y are independent random variables uniform taking values ​​in the sets {1, 2, 3} and {1, 2}, respectively.

As can know by simulating the expected ratio for the pair $(X, Y)$ such that $X > Y$ is generate, for example, 2000 values.

Comment: So you need to write out a simulation. Details depend very much on the tool you are using. One can also quickly compute without a simulation the actual probability that $X\gt Y$. It is $1/2$.

Comment: In the exercise of the book, it says you already have the 2000 values ​​for the pair (X, Y). It is a theoretical exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $X\gt Y$ can happen in two disjoint ways: (i) $X=2$ and $Y=1$ or (ii) $X=3$ (and $Y$ is anything).

(i) The probability that $X=2$ and $Y=1$ is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$. This is $\frac{1}{6}$.

(ii) The probability that $X=3$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Add. The probability that $X\gt Y$ is $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: This is the theoretical response, through a simulation I would like to know the estimated proportion. I wanted to know the error in this estimation.

Comment: Let $\bar{X}$ be experimental proportion. Then $\bar{X}$ has mean $\frac{1}{2}$ and variance $\frac{(1/2)(1/2)}{2000}$, so standard deviation about $0.011$. The random variable $\bar{X}$ has a close to normal distribution. So with probability $0.95$, the proportion in the simulation will be distance less than $(1.96)(0.011)$ from $\frac{1}{2}$.